# Is every cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for some $d \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, solution-verification

I believe the answer is no. I attach my proof below. I feel that my understanding isn't deep enough in some places, so hopefully that'll manifest in the proof and you will be able to point it out.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of the monic, irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^3-3x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x].$ There are three possible choices for $\alpha$, each of which are in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore there are three embeddings 
$\varphi: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, each of which have $\text{im}(\varphi) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Assume, for contradiction, that there exists an isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for some $d \in \mathbb{Q}$. This element $\sqrt[3]{d}$ has minimum polynomial $f_{\mathbb{Q}}^d(x)=x^3-d$. This polynomial has one real root and two complex roots, so there are three embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ into $\mathbb{C}$ - two of which have images not contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be one of the latter, so $\text{im}(\Phi) \not \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $\Phi \circ \phi$ is an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ into $\mathbb{C}$ whose image is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction as the image of each embedding of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ into $\mathbb{C}$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$. We conclude that $\phi$ doesn't exist. So not all cubic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are of the form in the title.

Comment: Your proof is good: the counterexample works.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample:

Assume that
$$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}$$
(the real root of the polynomial $x^3 - 3 x - 4$)  lies in a pure cubic extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{d}]$. We conclude 
$$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}= a + b\sqrt[3]{d} + c \sqrt[3]{d^2}\\
\omega \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}= a +\omega\, b\sqrt[3]{d} +\omega^2 c \sqrt[3]{d^2}\\
\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+\omega\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}}= a +\omega^2 b\sqrt[3]{d} +\omega\, c \sqrt[3]{d^2}$$

We conclude $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}= b \sqrt[3]{d}$, contradiction.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating, I don't follow from where you introduce omega.

Comment: @carraig:  $\omega$ is a cubic root of $1$. If one of the roots is in a pure cubic field, so will be the other two of them .

Comment: Given tge three equation above, multiply them byb$1,\omega^2,\omega$ in that order and add. Since $\omega^3=1$ we have $\omega^4=\omega$, and then for a _primitive_ cube root we have $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$. The terms containing $a,c,\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt3}$ all drop out leading to the claimed contradictory result.

Comment: How do you get the second and third equations?

Comment: @cut: that is a valid question. Here we have two cubic polynomials that have a common root, and since they are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, they will have the same roots ( all three of them).  That's why we have the equalities ( now indeed, we might have to flip the cubic roots on LHS for the last two equalities, but the argument will still work).  Hope it's a bit more clear.

Comment: I don’t see it. You’re referring to the polynomials $x^3-3x-4$ and $x^3-d$? Why do you claim that they have a common root? Also, $x^3-d$ need not be irreducible.

Comment: @cut: I am referring to the polynomial with root $a+ b \sqrt[3]{d} + c \sqrt[3] {d^2}$.  It is irreducible unless something not that complicated takes place. Btw,, $x^3 - d$ is irreducible if $d$ is not a cube of a rational.

Comment: What? You’re trying to disprove that $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{3}}+ \sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{3}} \in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for any $d\in\mathbb{Q}$, and for that you assume it’s true, so $\alpha$ can be written in the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$. Why talk about a polynomial that has $a+b\sqrt[3]{d}+c\sqrt[3]{d^2}$ as a root?